# Adding a reactive property to a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure what best practice in this example. I have an FAQ component that takes in a prop called `questions` which is an array of objects with property `question` and `answer`. The answers are hidden in an accordion and i'm creating a button that expands the accordion to also show the `answer`. However, I am not sure what the best approach to handle this. I need to add a property let's call it `isExpanded`. How would I do that? I thought about just creating a ref and JSON.parse/JSON.stringify to clone the prop, but is that really best practice?

```js
const props = defineProps({
  questions: {
    type: Array as () => {
      question: string;
      answer: string;
    }[],
    default: () => [],
  },
});
```

Comment: You are thinking in a correct way, Just add a property `isExpanded` in each questions object with default value as `false` and then on click on accordian, make it `true` for that specific object.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in a correct way, Just add a property `isExpanded` in each questions object with default value as `false` and then on click on accordion, make it `true` for that specific accordion on which user clicked.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [
        {
          id: 1,
          question: "Question 1",
          answer: "Answer 1",
          isExpanded: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          question: "Question 2",
          answer: "Answer 2",
          isExpanded: false,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          question: "Question 3",
          answer: "Answer 3",
          isExpanded: false,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExpand(item) {
      item.isExpanded = !item.isExpanded;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.card-header,
.card-content {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.card-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.card-body {
  height: auto;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata&display=swap"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <div class="card"
       v-for="item in questions"
       :key="item.id">
    <div class="card-header"
         @click.prevent="toggleExpand(item)">
      <span>{{ item.question }}</span>
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down" v-if="item.isExpanded"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up" v-if="!item.isExpanded"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body" v-if="item.isExpanded">
      <hr />
      <div class="card-content">{{ item.answer }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your not using vue3, nor a prop and props should not be mutated, not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @LawrenceCherone PO did not mentioned `Vue 3` so I just created a demo in Vue 2. Also, I thought he is looking for a solution "How to expanded the accordion" as I did not see `isExpanded` property in the object he mentioned. Might be I misunderstood his question. Let's wait for him to confirm about this.